# How to get new data from database (php) using ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to get new content from database with php, here is the code:

```
<?php
if($row['permalink'] == $_GET['contents']){
?>

<section id="workproject">
<div id="one">
<h1><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1> 
<img style="" src="portfolio/<?php echo $row['first_img']; ?>.jpg">
</div>
</section>

<?php
}
}
?>
```

So that works fine. So if I click on `<a href="?content=something">` then that would change the above content. However, I am try to figure hour how to get the result with jquery so that I do not have to reload the page.

I have managed to come this far:

```
$("#thums").click(function(){
$.ajax({ url: 'index.php',
data: {permalink: 'listaker'},
type: 'get',
success: function(output) {
$('#workproject').html(output);
}
});
});
```

But this loads the entire page from the start. is there a way that I can only reload the workproject id only. Or any other way to get this to work

Thanks

Comment: Is the `#thumbs` element a link? If that is the case you should `return false;` from the click handler. You should replace the `#workproject` element like this `$('#workproject').replaceWith(output);`

Comment: but the output is the fulll page, how can I remove bits from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#workproject').load('index.php?permalink=listaker #workproject');
```

instead of your $.ajax() code